# Kafka topic with multiple sources

Tags: apache-kafka

If I have 1 Kafka topic with 1 partition and multiple sources are posted in the **same** partition. What happens if 2 servers are trying to post in the same partition at the same time? Would it mix the information between both of those servers or one of them would wait until the other finishes?

Comment: Should be easy to test this. What have you observed?

Answer (score 1):

The producers will mix the messages in the partition.

Answer (score 0):

As per theory, events will be guaranteed to be appended in order per partition per producer. But if we are talking about multiple producers, then the behaviour will depend on the configuration set at the producer side. In particular, **max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1**. The reason being is if there are multiple in flight events and the first one failed, the second will get appended to the log earlier, thus breaking the ordering.

Have a glance at https://blog.softwaremill.com/does-kafka-really-guarantee-the-order-of-messages-3ca849fd19d2

Answer (score 0):

If somehow keys are same for both sources and every record, all of them will be recorded in the same partition (other partitions will remain empty)

If every source has a different key from each other but this key is used for every message from same source, then messages from different sources will be recorded at different partitions (if partition count is no less than source count).

If each value has a different key, regardless of sources, still kafka will mix them in partitions as I know.

In short, keys determine the partition of a message. Values with same key go to same partition. If every record has a unique key, Kafka will apply Round-Robin for incoming messages and each partition will have almost same amount of records.